# Word 2010 Keyboard Shortcut for Find Next

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I want to bind "Find Next" to F3, but I can't find the command in the Customize Keyboard Dialog.
It's easy enough to add "Find Next" to the Ribbon, but that did not allow me to bind a key to it.

Please point me in the right direction so I don't have to use my mouse. And yes, I want it to be F3, not Alt-Y or Control-PGUP/PGDOWN.  Get off my lawn!  :-)

If no one else can find it, I guess a macro is the next step.

[image: Customize Keyboard Dialog]

Comment: You get to this dialog by going `Find > Options > Customize Ribbon > Keyboard Shortcuts button`. I wasted time trying to perform the top answer in the "customize ribbon" box.

Comment: One correction to @Noumenon's comment: It's "File > Options" rather than "Find > Options"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is “Commands Not in the Ribbon” –> “RepeatFind”. 
(Of course you can also find it under “All Commands”.) 
And by the way, it is bound to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> by default.

Comment: +1 for locating it, but how stupid. When they have EditFind, couldn't they have thought of EditFindNext or something similar to keep them together? Also, a dialog like this seriously needs an option to find a command - a lengthy scrolling list is just bad UI.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I totally missed "Commands Not in the Ribbon". Shot in the dark but, would you happen to know of there is a PrevRepeatFind that I could bind to Shift-F3? (nothing jumped out at me. :-))

Comment: I don’t recall seeing that.  (Do do know that, in certain phases of the moon, you can use Ctrl+PageUp, right?)

Comment: Thanks again Scott. Control PageUp/PageDown are just what I wanted.

Comment: That is a bad name for the command. It should start with the word "Find".

Answer (score 5):

For Word 2007 at least, the commands are BrowseNext and BrowsePrevious under "All Commands":

[image]

To get to this dialog, go to Word Options / Customize / Keyboard shortcuts: Customize.

Answer (score 1):

Try these two macros for both directional searches:

```
Public Sub FindPrev()
  Selection.Find.Execute Forward:=False
End Sub
Public Sub FindNext()
  Selection.Find.Execute Forward:=True
End Sub
```